# Add an Integer Amount to a whole column?

Tags: mysql

Quick Question about MySQL;

I've got a table called 'userdata' and withit this one I got a 'coins' Column.

My Question is now is there a MySQL query command to add an X amount to all coins columns?

i.e

```
user: 1 Coins: 2
user: 2 Coins: 4
```

and I got several "user" accounts and I want them all to get +X amount.

Comment: `UPDATE userdata SET coins = coins+2`, or whatever value you want.

Comment: we're able to read all user names (through java) so we could probably add them while reading but i think there has to be an easier way to add X coins to all instead of read all users from the db, right?

Comment: @Mike W: you are right, but it should be an answer instead of a comment

Comment: Yup, @Mike your solution is working, thanks! U may write it down as an answer so i will flag it =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your tablename is userdata and your amount is 2 then you can add 2 to all coin fields in your table (every user gets two coins ;) )

`UPDATE userdata SET coin = coin + 2;`